# Woocommerce - Get WC_Order_Item_Product line discount

Tags: woocommerce, product, subtotal

i've been trying this for while with no success, i'm trying to get the WC_Order_Item_Product applied discount, OR even better, the line subtotal without tax BUT with discount once the order is already created in the backend, example:

```
(Backend)
Order #xxxx with 20% discount:
Item - Price - Amount - Total
Pen  -  10$   -   2    -  16$ (4$ discount)
Jar  -  30$   -   1    -  24$ (6$ discount)
```

Yup expensive jar... so i need either the subtotal (16$, 24$) or the discount so i can make the maths (4$, 6$) and also without taxes (as i said, subtotal).

Tried: $wc_order_item_product->get_subtotal() but it returns the full price without the discount, i need what the customer really paid (with the discount).

Thanks in advance guys, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is breaking is head already i've found the solution, the method "**get_total()**" from **WC_Order_Item_Product** DOESN'T give the total (sum of price+discount+taxes) instead, it gives the total without taxes (price+discount) =D

Answer (score 0):

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id);

foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ):

    $quantity          = $item->get_quantity();
    $line_subtotal     = $item->get_subtotal();// Line subtotal (non discounted)
    $line_total        = $item->get_total();// Line total (discounted)
    
    $line_discount     = intval($line_subtotal*abs($quantity)) - $line_total;// Line Discount

endforeach;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).